# Issues with queues Laravel (asynchronous functions)

Tags: php, laravel

I created a Laravel function using queues but it seems that it isn't working because I created 10 pdf files using `foreach`, and also a function with queues, but the execution time is the same.

This is my function with queues:

```
$encuesta = Encuesta::where('id', $request->interes_id)
        ->with('empresa')
        ->first();

$personas = EncuestaPuntaje::where('encuesta_id', $request->interes_id)
        ->with('persona')
        ->with('puntajes.carrera')
        ->get();

if ($personas->isEmpty()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'No hay encuestas resueltas.'], 401);
} else {
    foreach ($personas as $p) {
        PDF::dispatchNow($p['persona'], $p['puntajes'], $encuesta['empresa']['nombre']);
    }
```

And this is my job:

```
public function handle()
{
    $carreras = Carrera::where('estado', 1)->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $content = \PDF::loadView('reporte_interes', array('carreras' => $carreras, 'persona' => $this->persona, 'puntajes' => $this->puntajes))->output();

    $name = 'PDF/'.$this->empresa . '/INTERESES/' . $this->persona->nombres . '' . $this->persona->apellido_paterno . '.pdf';
    \Storage::disk('public')->put($name,  $content);
}
```

Here I generate 1 file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFRr.png)

And here I generate 10 files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMsvy.png)

It is my first time using queues in Laravel and I wanted the times to be the same.

Comment: what is the error? what you are trying to achieve actually ! I dont understand actually. would you please elaborate ?

Comment: When I generate 1 pdf it takes 1 second, but when I generate 10 files it takes a long time, so I am using queues to generate them at the same time.

Comment: okay. what is the error? can you show us the error you are getting?

Comment: No mistake, what I'm trying to do is generate the files at the same time

Comment: Can you show an example of the one with 1 vs 10?

Comment: yes i just updated the question

Comment: Plain logic says that if one file is generated for ~0.500 s, then 10 files will be generated in ~5 s. I don't see any error there. Side note, put querying for `$encuesta` in first line of else block.

Comment: yes but I want to generate the files synchronously, that's why I use queues

Comment: Because it is done in queue/job part of application, why do you think it would take less time for creating amount of files? In other words, if you would be right, you could expect like 100.000 files created in split of second just because that code block is in another class? It doesn't seem like right logic to me.

Comment: @Tpojka - [from the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues): *Queues allow you to defer the processing of a time consuming task, such as sending an email, until a later time. Deferring these time consuming tasks drastically speeds up web requests to your application.* Jean Pierre - I think you want to create the files ***a**synchronously*, not synchronously, and that's where your problem is.  I've posted an answer, please have a look.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I hope you're right because I presumed OP wants it be done immediately. I wanted to get that conclusion from their comment responses.

Comment: @Tpojka OP says they want to *generate the files at the same time*; in the context of wanting execution time for 1 and 10 to be the same, I understand that to mean they want the front end to take the same time, while at the same time (ie in parallel), the backend/queue is generating the files ... anyway, there is definitely some confusion :-) OP, help us out, does my answer help?

Comment: @JeanPierreAcostaTomaylla Does my answer help?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I also used dispatch, but I had to enter the terminal to activate the workers, and it gave me some problems on the server where I put my project into production.

Comment: @JeanPierreAcostaTomaylla Yes, you need something to process the queues, that is how queues work. That is how your front end can finish fast, while the jobs are still running on the back end. That is what you asked ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown is using `dispatchNow()`, but if you [check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#synchronous-dispatching):

> If you would like to dispatch a job immediately (synchronously), you may use the dispatchNow method. When using this method, the job will not be queued and will be run immediately within the current process

So `dispatchNow` is really not using queues at all.  The job runs immediately and holds up your front end (the controlling process), until it is done, just the same as if you weren't using queues at all.  You won't see any speed improvement.

Switch to using [normal dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dispatching-jobs), and the process will be deferred, and run *asynchronously*, in parallel but separate from your main task, allowing it to continue immediately.  Your main task will seem to finish much quicker, while in the background, the job is still running.

```
PDF::dispatch($p['persona'], ...
```